# How do I tell appStore that the upgrade of my app is mandatory?

Tags: app-store, upgrade

I have an app (v1.0) at appStore for a year or so. 
This app runs with and back-end (v1.0).

Now I want to deploy a new version, front-end and back-end. (v1.1)

But the front-end 1.0 is going to crash with the new back-end 1.1

How can force all users to upgrade my app?

Comment: Are you referring to the Apple App Store or some other app store?

Comment: Yes, I meant Apple App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  But, making the current version crash will certainly encourage current users to upgrade.  This, however, is pretty poor customer support.

It would be better if version 1.1 used some form of versioning to allow you to keep your backend 1.0 in place alongside 1.1.  Then if the new features are compelling enough, your users will certainly upgrade.